# Converting numpy array values into integers

Tags: python, numpy

My values are currently showing as `1.00+e09` in an array (type float64). I would like them to show `1000000000` instead. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you want to use `float64` at all, or do you want the data to actually just be integers?

Comment: I would like them to be integers. I am trying to write the values back into a csv file after some computation, and then convert the csv file to an excel file. Right now, the values on my excel files are showing up as the 1.00+e09 form, which I cannot work with on excel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make a sample array

```
In [206]: x=np.array([1e9, 2e10, 1e6])
In [207]: x
Out[207]: array([  1.00000000e+09,   2.00000000e+10,   1.00000000e+06])
```

We can convert to ints - except notice that the largest one is too large the default int32

```
In [208]: x.astype(int)
Out[208]: array([ 1000000000, -2147483648,     1000000])

In [212]: x.astype(np.int64)
Out[212]: array([ 1000000000, 20000000000,     1000000], dtype=int64)
```

Writing a csv with the default format (float) (this is the default format regardless of the array dtype):

```
In [213]: np.savetxt('text.txt',x)
In [214]: cat text.txt
1.000000000000000000e+09
2.000000000000000000e+10
1.000000000000000000e+06
```

We can specify a format:

```
In [215]: np.savetxt('text.txt',x, fmt='%d')
In [216]: cat text.txt
1000000000
20000000000
1000000
```

Potentially there are 3 issues:

- integer v float in the array itself, it's `dtype`
- display or print of the array
- writing the array to a csv file

Comment: Thank you, this helped loads. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a printing option, see the documentation: [printing options](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html). Briefly stated: you need to use the suppress option when printing:

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)  # for small floating point.

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True, formatter={'all':lambda x: str(x)})
```

Comment: But reread `suppress`.  It has to do with the display of small floating point, not large ones.  e.g. 1e-9.